# NAA flag got declined

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

Recently I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59688688/12416453) answer as NAA.

The answer was

> I have solved this issue by regenerate Key

While flagging as NAA it's mentions

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

IMO, it should possibly be a comment. I don't understand why my flag got declined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why would you think this should be posted as a comment? [Remember what comments are for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

It didn't ask for more information, nor did it suggest an improvement that could be made to the post.

**The answer was that the problem can be solved by regenerating the key.** That is an answer to the question.

It might be a *wrong* answer, but that's not what "not an answer" flags are meant to be used for; moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers. As the flag decline reason explains:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

It might need to be edited for grammar, but, again, that's not what "not an answer" flags are meant to be used for. They request the *deletion* of the answer, and there was no cause to delete this post.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll be more careful while flagging.

Comment: @Ch3steR No worries. It's a common mistake. Thanks for asking and being receptive to an explanation. We nevertheless appreciate you reviewing and working to keep the site clean. For more background, read the answer to the FAQ that I marked this as a duplicate of: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553

Comment: I'm a member for 6 months now not well versed with all of the SO rules. I mostly hang out in python and pandas tag, where answers are posted in the comments when a question is too basic, I totally forgot the comment section should be used for  *clarification*.

Comment: Answers should never be posted in the comments. Basic questions are fine and deserve a proper answer, unless they are otherwise unsuitable for Stack Overflow (e.g., too broad, unclear, a duplicate, etc.), and in that case, they should be *closed*, not answered in comments.